# Read multiple CSV files simultaneously (multithreading) using PHP Pthread

Tags: php, multithreading, csv, pthreads, fopen

I am trying to implement multi-threading in PHP using pthread.
What I want to do is, Suppose, I have 50 CSV files with lot many rows to work on. I need to read each row and insert it into database after checking on some validation criteria. So instead of reading one file at a time, I want to create 5 multiple threads at time which will process 5 different files simultaneously. If any of thread gets completed first, next queued file will join that thread.

For eg. I have 1X.CSV to 50X.CSV
I will start 5 threads to process 1X.CSV to 5X.CSV. Now 3X.CSV is quite small as compare to other four files. So its processing gets completed first. So 3rd thread gets free and it will look for next queued file i.e 6X.CSV. Each thread will work individually.

My problem is, When I am doing multi-threading without reading files, it is working good! But fopen() doesn't help me to read files in run() function. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? Below is my code. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
class AsyncLongAction extends Thread 
{

  public function __construct($s,$file)
  {
      $this->s = $s;
      $this->file = $file;
      //echo $file."<BR>";
  }

  public function run()
  {
     if($this->s)
     {
         printf("TID: %s is waiting for %s %s ...\n", $this->getCurrentThreadId(), $this->s, $this->file);
         //sleep($this->s);
         printf("%ss is over.\n<br>", $this->s);

         $handle = fopen($this->file,"r");
         echo $handle; //It is not giving any result.
         while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) != false)
         {
              $name = $filesop[0];
              $times = time();
              $sql = "<BR>".$name."---".$times."======".Thread::getCurrentThreadId();
              echo $sql;
         }
      fclose($handle);
     }
  }
}

$thread = array();
$files = glob("CSV/*"); // path is right, I have tried working with the same code without using pthread.

foreach($files as $key=>$file)
{
   $thread[] = new AsyncLongAction($key+1,$file);
}

$c= 0;
foreach($thread as $st)
{
    if($c < 3)
       $st->start();
    $st->join();
    $c++;
}
```

Comment: Try to echo `$this->file` it seems your were not getting `file` within `fopen` function within thread

Comment: Already tried. It is getting over there!

Answer (score 1):

You start a thread and immediately after that, you wait for it to finish. Then you start the next one and so on... Hint: If you had just logged what you do, you would have found that mistake yourself.